# How many parallel requests can be made using a single session token in a REST API

Tags: rest, session, token, session-state, sabre

I am working on an application which is going to be heavily dependent on Sabre API. The critical factor for the application is going to be performance when around a million users are accessing the API simultaneously.
After speaking to Sabre API support , all they told me is that they will provide max 50 session tokens at a time and you have to manage sessions at your end.
This leaves my question unanswered - will they be able to handle a million parallel requests?
So basically will we be able to make multiple requests using the same session token unless it expires?

Please help me understand their response.Below is the series of email conversation I had with the Sabre API support.

Hello Karam,

The limit will be the simultaneous sessions that is setup for your PCC. By default you can create up to 50 simultaneous tokens in CERT (50 simultaneous sessions) but the answer to your question is no, processing time from our side will not be impacted.

Regards,

---

Hello Sebastian
Thank you very much for being with me and helping me out with this.

So as you have mentioned that we can have 50 session tokens at a time, is it possible to make more than 1 simultaneous requests (asynchronous requests) using a single session token?
For example , we get a session token and store it at our end and use it to make multiple requests.

I ask this because , if not , then it would mean we can only make 50 parallell requests at a time (1 request per session token).
And if that is true then we might have to implement a request queue which will delay the responses for the end users.

Thanks

### Karam

Hello Karam,

Please see below my answers to your inquiries:

So as you have mentioned that we can have 50 session tokens at a time, is it possible to make more than 1 simultaneous requests (asynchronous requests) using a single session token?
For example , we get a session token and store it at our end and use it to make multiple requests.

It is not possible, It is actually not a Sabre Web Services related behavior but how Sabre host works. Sabre is a synchronous system, once a request has been sent, you need to wait until receiving a response back in order to run a second call. Otherwise you will receive a message like “PREVIOUS ENTRY ACTIVE” or similar.

I ask this because , if not , then it would mean we can only make 50 parallell requests at a time (1 request per session token).
And if that is true then we might have to implement a request queue which will delay the responses for the end users.

It will depend on the session manager and the customer’s needs but most of our customers don’t need to consume 1000 simultaneous sessions. In any case, once you are a webservices subscriber you can define and request to your account executive the amount of tokens that best meets your needs.

Hope this helps!

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, you cannot use the same session/token for multiple parallel requests...(Sabre keeps the session state, and that affects the result of your next request)

What they recommend is to create a session manager, so you'll have your session queue and use them and "ignore" them as you need them. That way you can have sessions for query only and sessions for touching a PNR, you can also manage your own expiration time, or "keep alive" routine.